# Android - JQuery google maps

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, dictionary

I'm creating an app that uses Phonegap and JQuerymobile. It's possible to insert a google map in my app using JQuery? How can i do it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this source

[GMap Demo App Source](http://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/libbybaldwin/GMap-Demo-App&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNF38kZ7J7LfuwJ_kD1WhrV2Xl-r9Q)

You can find it also at Google Play

[GMap Demo by AppLaud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mds.gmapdemo)